# how to filter the filename based on special character in html page in angular?

Tags: angular

I have got a list of uploaded files in which file names look like this-

`fc00a501-2536-4599-b180-ad661491e8f9|test.pdf`

I need the name only after the `|` symbol.

I don't want to change the name of the file. I just want to show the file name without the hash.

I can't seem to figure out how to achieve this

Here's the template code that renders the file list.

```
<mat-list role="list">
  <mat-list-item role="listitem" *ngFor="let item of uploadedFiles">
    <div class="list-files">
      <span>{{item}}</span>
      <div class="btn-custom" (click)="delete(item)"> Delete</div>
    </div>
  </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

Comment: item.split('|')[1] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a perfect use case for a custom pipe.

You could create a custom pipe like this:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'nameWithoutHash'
})
export class NameWithoutHashPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(fullName: any, args?: any): any {
    return fullName.split('|')[1];
  }

}
```

You could then use it like this:

```
<mat-list role="list">
  <mat-list-item role="listitem" *ngFor="let item of uploadedFiles">
    <div class="list-files">
      <span>{{item | nameWithoutHash}}</span>
      <div class="btn-custom" (click)="delete(item)"> Delete</div>
    </div>
  </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

---

> Here's a [**working Sample Code Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-file-name-list-without-hash) for your ref.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking into [Angular pipes](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#custom-pipes). Pipes are used in the HTML page, and don't require anything in script. They allow modification of text.

You could then create a custom pipe that strips anything before a pipe, using regular TS.

`str = str.substring(str.indexOf("|") + 1);`